# How can I print the top 5 topics in my classification model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working my scikit-learn in python for my topic classification program. Scikit metrics prints the top probability of a document being in a class. However, what I want to know is when I provide an input document X to my classifier, the classifier will generate a vector of different topics.

Every value in that generated vector will represent a probability that it belongs to some topic.
Then document X will be classified as topic Y corresponding to the highest probability (among 88 values).
Instead of taking the highest probability and assigning the corresponding topic to document X, I want to know the top 5 topics with highest probabilities.How can I do so.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(matrix, label)

y_train_pred = model1.predict(matrix_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

The general idea:

1. Get the probabilities (use log_proba for better numerical robustness).
2. Sort the probabilities for each document (row of the probability matrix).
3. Once they are sorted you will find the top 5 in the last five columns.

Instead of actually sorting the probabilities, [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort) gives you the order of the columns. Since each column corresponds to a topic, you then know the ranking of topics for each document.

```
lnprobs = model1.predict_log_proba(matrix_test)
order = np.argsort(lnprobs, axis=1)

print(order[:, -5:])  # print top 5 topics for each document
```

**Edit:**
Let's disect the above piece of code for clarification:

`lnprobs`is a matrix (2D-array), where each value contains the logarithm of the probability that a document is belongs to a topic. Each row corresponds to a document and each column to a topic.

Now look at the first row of `lnprobs`; it may contain something like `[-0.7, -3.7, -2.1, -5.8, -1.2, -10.9, -7.2]`. There are 88 entries, one for each topic, but for simplicity let's assume there are only 7 topics now.

If you want to know the highest probabilities, you have to sort them. In sorted order they are `[-10.9, -7.2, -5.8, -3.7, -2.1, -1.2, -0.7]`. Now, we know the top 5 probabilities are -5.8 to -0.7. However, we no longer know which topic they belong to.

This is where `np.argsort` comes into play. Instead of simply sorting the values, it tells us where the sorted values come from. We get this: `[5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0]`. The information is the 5th vaule has the lowest probability (-10.9), and the 0th value has the highest probability (-0.7).

Comment: Hi, so on trying this, I get an output like:

[[38 11  6 66  0]
 [20 13 11  0  1]
 [61 11  0 13  1]
 ..., 
 [19 30 13  0  1]
 [13 34 75  0  1]
 [ 0 46  3  1 40]]
How can I find out, which class are these probabilities referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd expect. It means that e.g. the first document's top five topics are 38, 11, 6, 66, and 0.

Comment: Oh, I get you. So, then since 66 is the highest, it assigns the document to that topics. Is there a way I can access the topics/labels for the probabilities that were printed out just to cross check the classification?

Comment: Actually, 0 is the topic with the highest probability, 66 is the second highest (the probabilities are not shown). How to access and print the topic labels depends on how you store/encode them.

Comment: I am a bit confused. So, if these aren't the probabilities and are topics instead, how do I know 0 has the highest probability? Need your help to understand this better. Thanks

Comment: I get the idea now however, if I consider this array: [38 11 6 66 0], given that 0 has the highest probability: how do I know which topic is this 0 representing since out of 88, only top 5 are being presented and for each document, these top 5 topics will vary.

Comment: Python starts counting at 0, so 0 represents the first topic. Let me predict your next question: which is the first topic? Answer: I don't know. That depends on how you code topics.

Comment: I know which the first topic is since I get that from *model.classes_* and it should remain the same. However, is there a way in which i can print maybe the topic labels(0 to 87) and corresponding top 5 like using a zip function or something. And what if instead of *argsort* if I had used only *np.sort*?